# Using Opt + 1 shortcut to switch to Desktop 1

Tags: keyboard, mission-control

I feel a little silly asking this since I think it used to work.  I would like to use the key combination <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to switch to Desktop 1 in Mission Control.  The current mapping is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> but when I try to remap it in the settings, I can't seem to be able to assign <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, and I'm not sure why.  I have a screen share to illustrate this. I'm using macOS Monterey Version 12.2.1 (which is currently up to date).  It's been suggested that only the key combinations colored orange on the virtual keyboard can be used.  However, I don't understand why.  Are they mapped to something else? Is there anyway to unmap them?

[Screenshare](https://youtu.be/ujaE7bFYZgo)

Additionally, I have a mac mini where I have no problem using that key combination:[image]

Comment: Will it let you change it to anything else? Is only opt/number blocked?

Comment: Which Mac are you using? Which macos version do you have installed?

Comment: I'm using macOS Monterey Version 12.2.1. Yes, I can map to other keys (e.g. command+1 or control+1)